# How to control Google Firebase Console Timestamp format; 24 hours vs am pm?

Tags: firebase, timestamp, format, firebase-console

In one db I get
December 12, 2021 at 5:00:00 PM UTC+1
In another db I get
12 December 2021 at 18:00:00 UTC+1

How do I change firebase settings to make the first db also displays timestamp as 24 hour clock in the console?